# Using TextInputLayout layout without changing Application Theme

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

When I am using textInputLayout withOut AppCompat theme in the application, I am not able to inflate the layout and my app is crashing.  When I tried setting Appcompat theme for TextInputLayout alone, it worked fine for devices with API's above 21, but it is still crashing for pre lollipop devices. Is there a way to use TextInputLayout on PreLollipop devices without using AppCompat theme for the whole application ?

Comment: have you used support design library ? if not then compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1' in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextInputLayout needs a theme derived from a Design theme. First you need to get a context with such theme.

```
val themedContext = ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_Design_Light)
```

In here `context` is an activity. Now you have two options:

#### 1) Inflate the input layout from XML

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(themedContext)
inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_input_layout, inputParent, true)
// Find the input layout and edit text by ID and work with them.
```

`inputParent` is a view group where the input layout will be attached after inflation.

#### 2) Create the input layout in Java

```
val inputLayout = TextInputLayout(themedContext)
val editText = EditText(inputLayout.context)
inputLayout.addView(editText)
inputParent.addView(inputLayout)
```

I recommend option 1 because it's what most people are used to when defining view hierarchies. it may help you avoiding unexpected results.

Or just use the AppCompat theme and AppCompatActivity because why the hell not.